# How do I get the water to completely drain from my tub with a drain in the end wall?

Tags: water, drain, floor, bathtub

I have an old school bathtub where the drain is vertical at the end of the tub instead of flat and in the middle. So the all of the water doesn’t roll down all the way and some of it ends up sitting, stuck in the middle of the tub without draining. Any easy fix ideas besides replacing the tub or construction to move the drain?

[image]

Comment: Will need a picture of the whole tub.  I imagine you will need to raise the other end up a tiny bit(1/4 inch), but construction of the tub is important to know.  If on legs, easy, if not then the base/floor will need adjustment to maintain tub support.

Answer (score 3):

Re-install the tub with proper slope is the only fix for this other than mopping it up or squeegeeing it out as suggested in comments.

The end of the tub away from the drain should be adequately higher than the drain end to allow water to drain out without leaving puddles. As it's not, the tub is set wrong, (or the building has settled) with that end too low.